# React useState throws error on Highcharts mouseOver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, use-state

I have a react typescript app with a highcharts chart. I want to update a "price" label (outside of the highcart) based on the data I get when a user is hovering their mouse over part of the chart.

The mouseOver callback is working fine, and I can successfully log the data I want to the console. But when I try to update the state of price using the useState hook for setPrice I get an error from highcharts. If I comment the setPrice line out, no errors. Any thoughts?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'yAxis')
    at highstock.src.js:24009
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c.getAnchor (highstock.src.js:23992)
    at c.refresh (highstock.src.js:24517)
    at c.runPointActions (highstock.src.js:27941)
    at c.onContainerMouseMove (highstock.src.js:27502)
```

Here's some pseudo code for how i've implemented it:

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState<number>(0)

options = {
  ...
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function(e:any) {
            price = // logic to fetch price based on mouse position 
            console.log(price)   
            setPrice(price)
          }
        }
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

And the html (styled-components)

```
<Price>{ price }</Price>
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(price)`?

Comment: Simply a number, like 200. And I've assured that it's of type number.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a problem with my data. I'm going to try to repro this with a much simpler data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data isn't probably available immediately that's why it's returning a null data. However, you can set the data asynchronously using a setTimeout delay like so.

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState<number>(0)

options = {
  ...
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function(e:any) {
            price = // logic to fetch price based on mouse position 
            console.log(price)   
            setTimeout(() => { // This is where the delay comes in
            setPrice(price)
            }, 0)
          }
        }
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is there is a time delay to get that data back to you.  Try async/await and then set your state back on those results.